# Jolly jumper sequence

Tags: java, array

Another [challenge from CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/43/) that's causing me great pain...

Trying to find out if a sequence if a Jolly Jumper, which is

> A sequence of n > 0 integers is called a jolly jumper if the absolute values of the difference between successive elements take on all the values 1 through n-1.

I ended up adapting [this idea](https://gist.github.com/sachin-handiekar/1020988) into this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //File file = new File(args[0]);
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            String[] numbersString = line.split(" ");
            int[] numbers = new int[numbersString.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbersString[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(isJolly(numbers));
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static String isJolly(int[] array) {
        List listResults = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            int result = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i + 1]);
            if (result == 0) {
                return "Not jolly";
            }
            if (result >= array.length) {
                return "Not jolly";
            }
            if (listResults.contains(result)) {
                return "Not jolly";
            }
            listResults.add(result);
        }
        return "Jolly";
    }
}
```

I tested it with a few examples locally and it worked, but when I submit the code I don't get any sequence to appear as jolly. What mistakes am I making?

Comment: The first mistake is - `what happens when there is 1 or 0 element in the array?`

Comment: Also, why use an `ArrayList`?(Although this is not an error) Just use an array with length - `arr.length - 1`, initialize all value to 0 and add a value at its location. For e.g. `result[Math.abs(array[i] - array[i + 1]) - 1] = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i + 1]);`. This way you wouldn't have to check for `contains()`. If `result[i] != 0` then it is 'Not Jolly'.

Comment: @yadav_vi, if there's 1 element on the array, the program doesn't enter the instructions inside the `for`, returning 'Jolly? - because a single number is a ?jolly? sequence. If there's an empty array, well, yes, the program explodes. The `ArrayList` was already on the program I adapted and it seemed a good idea at the time. But yes, maybe it's a bit too much...

Comment: Never edit a question for which some answer has been given. Read the FAQs.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Reverted it to the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution seems generally sound. I would make a few changes:

```
if (result == 0) {
    return "Not jolly";
}
if (result >= array.length) {
    return "Not jolly";
}
if (listResults.contains(result)) {
    return "Not jolly";
}
```

Can easily be:

```
if (result == 0 || result >= array.length || listResults.contains(result)) {
    return "Not jolly";
}
```

Close the `reader`. Don't use `System.exit(0)`.

When you use an `ArrayList`, and you know the size it is going to be, first of all, ***it's a generic type! Set it so that it only accepts Integers.*** Also, set the size:

```
List<Integer> listResults = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
```

But the biggest problem is that your code has a bug in it. It says:

> Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename. Each line in this file is one test case. Each test case will contain an integer n < 3000 followed by n integers representing the sequence. The integers are space delimited.

Notice that the first integer is not in the sequence, so the solution that works will:

1. Create a new `array` that holds all the numbers from `1` to the first integer in the array.
2. Loop through each difference. Set `result[difference]` to `0`. `-1` to the first integer in the array if it was not already `0`.
3. Check if the first integer in the array is `0`. If it is, return `true`, otherwise, return `false`.

#### Solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            String[] numbersString = line.split("\\s+");
            int[] numbers = new int[numbersString.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbersString[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(isJolly(numbers) ? "Jolly" : "Not jolly");
        }
        reader.close();
    }

    public static boolean isJolly(int[] array) {
        int[] result = new int[array[0]];
        for (int i = 0; i < array[0]; i++) {
            result[i] = i;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            int diff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i + 1]);
            if(result.length > diff && result[diff] != 0) {
                array[0]--;
                result[diff] = 0;
            }
        }
        return array[0] == 1;
    }
    
}
```

I was able to solve the challenge with this.

Comment: The this is that, when I submit it to CodeEval, the only output it gives is a load of "not jollys" - and since I can't see the input sequences, I can't help but question where is my error... about `ArrayList`: I admit I'm not particularly familiar with it, so I'm a bit still in the dark with it.

Comment: @RodolfoDias I have edited my question as I have found the bug in your code.

Comment: Hmm, it's giving me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`...

Comment: It's still not detecting "jolly" sequences on CodeEval - but it detects them when I test it with a file on my PC. It probably has something to do with the input format - and since I don't have access to it, I can't know what's wrong here. In spite of all this, I'm accepting your answer :)

Comment: @RodolfoDias I have created a working solution that will actually work. Try it!

Comment: Use of a linked list is often a bad idea. In this case, it turns an O(n) algorithm into O(n^2).

Comment: @200_success Better? (Used array)

Answer (score 3):

As a simple comment, a function called `isJolly` should probably return a boolean. Then, the calling function can use that boolean to print either "Jolly" or "Not jolly".

Answer (score 3):

The use of an `ArrayList`, especially one of unspecified capacity, is a poor choice in terms of efficiency: you could end up reallocating and recopying the list many times as it expands.

The use of collections without specifying the data type has been considered substandard for about a decade.  (Generics were introduced in J2SE 5.0, released in September 2004.)  Your data structure should have been declared as

```
List<Integer> listResults = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
```

However, a more appropriate data structure for this problem would be a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

```
public static boolean isJolly(int[] array) {
    BitSet seenIntervals = new BitSet(array.length);
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int interval = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i - 1]);
        if (interval == 0 || interval >= array.length) {
            return false;
        }
        if (seenIntervals.get(interval)) {
            return false;
        }
        seenIntervals.set(interval);
    }
    assert(seenIntervals.cardinality() == array.length - 1);
    return true;
}
```

For clarity, I've renamed your `result` to `interval`, and `listResults` to `seenIntervals`.